# is it possible store images and documents in database.com

Tags: database.com

I have a requirement where image data and few files has to be stored in database.com and display to Salesforce site users. I have a number of database.com licence and using salesforce sites need to upload images and files to database.com  and display the same to users in sites. Can anybody help me in this. My primary question is how to store images/files in database.com.

Answer (score 2):

Database.com has been merged back into the platform in general, as a new license type i believe, as such http://www.database.com now redirects to http://www.salesforce.com/platform/database

Given Database.com is now Force.com and your primary question, there are options for storing files, there are many ways to do this, each with its own pros and cons and limits on file size. This help topic gives a good overview and summary of each. [Differences between Files, Salesforce CRM Content, Salesforce Knowledge, Documents, and Attachments](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_differences.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: is ther any way we can have a test?.

Comment: Sorry, a test for what?

Comment: Where we can have a test login and upload some images

Comment: Sure just create yourself a Force.com Developer org, http://developer.force.com and click Join Now in top right corner of the page.

Comment: This is a good intro into Force.com Sites, http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites btw

Comment: So you mean Force.com and database.com are integrated now?. Or simply the salesforce data goes to database.com is it? So then storing an image/file in databse.com is nothing but creating attachments/documents in force.com am I correct?  If I am then can I use my database.com licence in site to upload and view files?

Comment: Yes it would appear so, i cannot see anyway to signup to a new Database.com org anymore, yet my old one still works, and shows my user as a Database.com Admin license.

Comment: I'm also trying to find from Salesforce what's going on, i would have expected some kind of announcement tbh, but cannot find one either. In either case, even if Database.com as we knew it was still up, yes it's based on the same backend storage as Force.com, only difference would be you could not run Force.com Sites in it, you had to build a Heroku app create a front end to a Database.com org, perhaps they didn't get enough traction on this and have decided to roll it back into Force.com...

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any way to create an object/table in database.com?

Comment: Sure you can use the options in the UI under the Setup menu, see Create and the Objects or programatically via the Metadata API. THere are also Java frameworks integrated with Database.com that automatically create object/table based on your POJO's.

Answer (score 0):

I have just created account  through this link https://database.secure.force.com/en/signup/. for login you can use login.database.com.

Note: This is trial version for developers.